# 4 div inline images, is this possible?

Tags: html, inline

So I am a little confused about how i would go about this?

I am looking to arrange 4 images. 2 on the top inline, one below these images and one that sits on both vertically.

Could someone help me achieve this - [here is a link to an example](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39024241/possiblle.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the images are all 100px wide, the smaller images are 50px tall, the tall one is 120px tall, and the wide one is 220px wide, with 20px of spacing between them, you get this HTML:

```
<div id="ImagesOuter">
  <div id="Image1"><img src="..." width="100" height="50" alt="" /></div>
  <div id="Image2"><img src="..." width="100" height="50" alt="" /></div>
  <div id="Image3"><img src="..." width="100" height="120" alt="" /></div>
  <div id="Image4"><img src="..." width="220" height="50" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#ImagesOuter {
  /* Combined Width */
  width: 340px;
  /* Resize according to float content */
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* IE7-8 support for float clear-fix */
*+html #ImagesOuter {
  min-height: 1%;
}

/* Proper rendering */
#ImagesOuter > div > img {
  display: block;
}

#Image1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

#Image2 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

#Image3 {
  float: right;
}

#Image4 {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
}
```

A fiddle showing this with simple grey boxes:
http://jsfiddle.net/mcZRK/

Feel free to play around with the dimensions to match what you're trying to do.